# Laravel Socialite: Knowing who the user is on callback?

Tags: laravel, api, github-api, laravel-socialite

So I've just coded the basics with socialite, but on the callback the only parameter being passed is `?code` being passed by git. I need a way to authenticate my user on the callback.

I need to store the token to the db, but who do I assign the token to? The callback is to a stateless API so it would probably have to be sent to github, then github send it back with the callback?

If anyone has a way I can solve this issue, please let me know.

Update, I can pass data with the link to GitHub, but it doesn't send it back?

```
return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->with(['user_id' => 1])->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
```

Comment: You have to create a new user and assign this code to that user. When user will try to sign in via Github again, you just need to lookup a user with that code.

Comment: I'm linking it to an existing user via my API. This isn't for user creation.

Comment: Seen your update. Had almost the same situation. I was not able to find a way to pass data and retrieve it afterwards, so I used sessions...